# Detecting a Bad File

Tags: 7.0-nougat, malware, remote-control, dual-sim, lg-g-stylo

I have an **LG STYLUS 3** phone and suspect that it may be remotely controlled or linked to another person. What do I look for to know whats up?

Comment: how and why did you suspect that? Pictures please